# SQL Отчет по затраченному времени с разбивкой по дням

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

Возможно ли вообще такое реализовать?

Имеются 4 таблицы в БД MySQL

| Users | Elapsed_time | Tasks | Grops |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | id |
| Name | date | title | title |
|  | user_id | grop_id |  |
|  | task_id |  |  |
|  | minutes |  |  |

в конце хочется получить отчет в виде таблицы с разбивкой по дням

| GROUPS | USERS | TASKS | 01 jan | 02 jan | 03 jan | 01 feb | 02 feb | 03 feb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| group 1 | user 1 | task 1 | 10 | 20 | 30 |  |  | 10 |
| group 1 | user 1 | task 22 |  |  | 40 | 50 | 10 |  |
| group 1 | user 22 | task 1 |  |  | 20 | 20 |  |  |
| group 1 | user 22 | task 333 |  |  |  | 30 | 30 |  |
| group 1 | user 333 | task 22 |  |  |  |  |  | 40 |
| group 2 | user 333 | task 333 | 20 | 20 |  |  | 10 |  |
| group 2 | user 333 | task 4444 |  | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |
| group 2 | user 4444 | task 1 | 40 |  |  |  |  |  |
| group 2 | user 4444 | task 333 |  |  | 20 | 20 |  |  |
| group 2 | user 55555 | task 22 |  |  |  | 30 | 30 |  |
| group 2 | user 55555 | task 4444 |  |  |  |  | 40 |  |
| group 2 | user 55555 | task 55555 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |

На данный момент смог построить такой запрос

```sql
SELECT 
    b_tasks_elapsed_time.ID, 
    b_user.NAME, 
    b_tasks.TITLE, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) AS year, 
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) AS month, 
    ROUND(NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) = 1 THEN b_tasks_elapsed_time.MINUTES ELSE 0 END)/60, 0), 2) AS day_01,
    ROUND(NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) = 2 THEN b_tasks_elapsed_time.MINUTES ELSE 0 END)/60, 0), 2) AS day_02,
...    
    ROUND(NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) = 30 THEN b_tasks_elapsed_time.MINUTES ELSE 0 END)/60, 0), 2) AS day_30,
    ROUND(NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) = 31 THEN b_tasks_elapsed_time.MINUTES ELSE 0 END)/60, 0), 2) AS day_31
FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time
INNER JOIN b_user ON b_tasks_elapsed_time.USER_ID = b_user.ID
INNER JOIN b_tasks ON b_tasks_elapsed_time.TASK_ID = b_tasks.ID
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) = 2023 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE) = 11 AND b_user.ID LIKE '251'
GROUP BY b_tasks_elapsed_time.ID
```

Может поможете sql-запросом, ссылка или путь в каком направлении двигаться, что бы решить задачу.
Любая помощь приветствуется.

Comment: Забиваете в Гугле как использовать JOIN, GROUP, SUM и DATE для mysql, читаете и постепенно, по-шагово создаете запрос.

Comment: Это сводная таблица (pivot table). Так что по термину PIVOT и ищите темы и решения.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, уже обновил свой запрос и выложил в первом посте.
Теперь задался вопросом можно и нужно ли его оптимизировать?
Если да, то как?

Comment: Упоминается в запросе ``b_tasks_elapsed_time.CREATED_DATE``. В описании таблиц таких нет?

Comment: ``GROUP BY b_tasks_elapsed_time.ID`` - вызывает сомнение. Ожидается группировка по group_id,user_id,task_id. Приведите пример данных и желаемый результат, ему соответствующий.